# VHDL Simple 12buttons keyboard not working in the simulation

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I wrote a very light edge detector which is the interface for buttons:

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

    entity Button is
        port ( clk :         in STD_LOGIC ;
                 signal_in : in STD_LOGIC;
              output :   out STD_LOGIC);
    end Button;

    architecture EdgeDetector of Button is
        signal signal_d:STD_LOGIC;
        begin

        process(clk)
        begin
            if clk= '1' and clk'event then
                signal_d<=signal_in;
          end if;
        end process;

         output<= (not signal_d) and signal_in; 
    end EdgeDetector;
```

By testing it with modelsim it seems there is the correct behaviour: the output will be high for only one clock cycle period, even if the button is pressed for a longer period.

The previous entity is a component used in a bigger entity, which is the Keyboard: it is in charge of give in output 4 bits in order to describe which  button was pressed.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Keyboard is
    port ( ck_in :      in STD_LOGIC := '0';
             data_in :  in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0) := (others=>'-');
             data_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end Keyboard;

architecture rtl of Keyboard is
    signal NUM : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 downto 0) := (others=>'-');   
begin   

num_0 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(0),NUM(0));
num_1 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(1),NUM(1));
num_2 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(2),NUM(2));
num_3 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(3),NUM(3));
num_4 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(4),NUM(4));
num_5 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(5),NUM(5));
num_6 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(6),NUM(6));
num_7 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(7),NUM(7));
num_8 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(8),NUM(8));
num_9 : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(9),NUM(9));
num_on : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(10),NUM(10));
num_off : entity work.Button port map(ck_in,data_in(11),NUM(11));           

with NUM select
    data_out <= "0000" when "000000000001", --0
                   "0001" when "000000000010", --1
                    "0010" when "000000000100", --2
                    "0011" when "000000001000", --3
                    "0100" when "000000010000", --4
                    "0101" when "000000100000", --5
                    "0110" when "000001000000", --6
                    "0111" when "000010000000", --7
                    "1000" when "000100000000", --8
                    "1001" when "001000000000", --9
                    "1010" when "010000000000", --ON
                    "1100" when "100000000000", --OFF
                    "----" when others;
end rtl;
```

But when I try to check the correct behaviour of the Keyboard entity the Button seems to works in a wrong way. Infact as soon as the data_in is "000000000001" the NUM is "00000000000X" (**I dont know why "X" instead of "1"**) and there is no change on data_out. After one clock cycle period, keeping the same data_in, the NUM comes to "000000000000" and of course data_out will be "----" for all the time.

This happen only at the first setting, because next data_in the system works as expected.

So the question is: why giving a correct data_in at the beggining the Button gives in output a bit=X instad of 1?

Comment: why do you initialise `data_in` to `(others=>'-')`? If it's a physical input, the initialisation value is meaningless. You haven't shown how you drive `data_in` in your test case. To replicate the real world, it should transition from `'0'` to `'1'` and back.

Comment: Scary_jeff you are right about data_in initialise (not usefull at all). I updated my question because this strange behaviour is only faced at the first pressure of a button. After the system works fine. In modelsim the data_in bit is '0' all the time and '1' just for a time > of the clock cycle period.

Comment: Does the `clk` run all the time, or does it only start at the same time as your first button press? At time 0, your `signal_d` signal has not been initialised, so until the first `clk` edge, `output` would be `'X'`.

Comment: Clock signal is always present with a duty cycle of 50%.
At the beginning data_in and NUM are "UUUUUUUUUUUU" while data_out is "----". After 5 clock cycles I forced data_in "000000000001", in the same istant NUM becames "00000000000U" (so data_out is still "----").
I think you found the issue, I should set `signal signal_d : STD_LOGIC := '0'` in the Button's architecture. Later I will try it. Thanks a lot @scary_jeff

Comment: well, giving a default value to signal_d in the beginning, did not solved the issue :(....

Comment: Your question doesn't present a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're asking scary_jeff to guess and leaving some part of your reading audience guessing what is in your instantiated entity Button.